# Tensorflow embeddings InvalidArgumentError: indices[58,10] = 1755 is not in [0, 1486)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, word-embedding

I`m trying to create neural network using KERAS. and trying to create a glove CNN text classification model. But however I tried there has been always an issue with the embedding layers

```py
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/emotion/glove/', 'glove.6B.100d.txt'))
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()
```

and this the embedding_matrix

```py
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
         
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

the final embedding layer

```py
from keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_UTTERANCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

when training the model i had this error :

```py
Node: 'model_10/embedding_7/embedding_lookup'
indices[57,7] = 2124 is not in [0, 1486)
     [[{{node model_10/embedding_7/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_10667]
```